# Is it possible to detect tail call optimization in WebKit?

Tags: javascript, optimization, webkit, tail-recursion

I have a recursive function and exhausting the call stack is an issue I run into sometimes. I know I can use streams, promises with setTimeout, but I would like to just write code that triggers tail call optimization. So far only [Webkit](https://www.webkit.org/blog/4054/es6-in-webkit/) seem to have implemented tail call optimization (TCO). Other than knowing the theory, is there any way do check if my code will trigger TCO, either with devtools or by examining the output of the Webkit compiler?

Answer (score 6):

I know it's not perfect, but I think it's the best option we have currently.

Consider this function:

```
"use strict";

function detectTCO() {
    const outerStackLen = new Error().stack.length;
    // name of the inner function mustn't be longer than the outer!
    return (function inner() {
        const innerStackLen = new Error().stack.length;
        return innerStackLen <= outerStackLen;
    }());
}
```

`Error.stack` is not standard, but it has basic support in all modern browsers. It has different values in different browsers, nonetheless, when a longer named function tail-calls a shorter named one, the stack trace:

- with TCO: gets shorter, because the stack frame of the outer function gets replaced by the stack frame of the inner function.
- without TCO: gets longer, because the stack frame of the inner function gets appended.

As of now, this returns `true` for Safari, and `false` for other browsers, which is the current TCO support.

```js
"use strict";

function detectTCO() {
 const outerStackLen = new Error().stack.length;
    // name of the inner function mustn't be longer than the outer!
    return (function inner() {
     const innerStackLen = new Error().stack.length;
     return innerStackLen <= outerStackLen;
    }());
}

document.getElementById('result').innerText = detectTCO() ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

```css
#result {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
Is TCO available? 
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This is very clever. I want to wait a bit before accepting this answer. It must not give false positives and since JavaScriptCore is the only engine with *unflagged* TCO support, it's difficult to test.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Sure thing. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter, node gives a positive answer too, if you run it with the `--harmony` parameter.

Comment: I just tested this in node 7.5.0 and 6.7.0, without the `--harmony` flag and both environments returned `true` for `detectTCO()`. In which version of node did V8 support TCO?

Comment: Wow. It is. I had no idea. I can't seem to find the release date.

Comment: Very clever indeed. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This returns true in Chrome 72.

Answer (score 1):

Could utilize `.toString()` , `RegExp.test()` to check for `return` statement followed by underscore, or $ sign , a-z characters;  followed by open parenthesis followed by any characters followed by closing parenthesis

```js
function forEach(arr, callback, start) {
  if (0 <= start && start < arr.length) {
    callback(arr[start], start, arr);
    return forEach(arr, callback, start + 1); // tail call
  }
}

console.log(/return [_a-z$]+\(.*\)/i.test(forEach.toString()))
```

Comment: Clever, but I want to know if the JS engine **detect** and do TCO, not if the JS engine **should** be able to do TCO. For now, the JS engine being JavaScriptCore.

Comment: But since regex is fun, here is one that test if a function is recursive; `/function ([\w]+)(?:[^]+)return \1\(.*\)/`. Also your regex could be improved to cover function names with digits in them `/return [\w$]+\(.*\)/`. And an unicode aware version would be `/return [\w$]+\(.*\)/u` for es6.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do it in the most idiotic way - run tail recursive function in try, catch block with some "big" arguments. If it throws then TCO is not working.